# Switch between applications - pywinauto

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I am trying to loop between applications at a certain interval, for now, I came up with this just wanting to see it work, but I am not able to "focus" on the Chrome application.
Note: multiple applications could be running (Chrome, Notepad, PyCharm, Skype)
but I only want to switch between Notepad and Chrome
So far I came up with this:

```
from pywinauto import application
from time import sleep
notepad = application.Application()
chrome = application.Application()

chrome.start("chrome.exe")
notepad.start("notepad.exe")


def loopApps():
    while True:
        chrome.connect(title_re="Google Chrome")
        chrome_dialog = chrome.top_window_()
        chrome_dialog.Minimize()
        print("[+] Sleeping 10 seconds")
        sleep(10)
        notepad.connect()
        notepad_dialog = notepad.top_window_()


loopApps()
```

I am not sure that this could be done using `pyautogui` as I've looked into the docs...
This is not useful(and it's outdated)
[how to switch between two application using pywinauto 0.5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222050/how-to-switch-between-two-application-using-pywinauto-0-5-4)

Comment: Is notepad_dialog.set_focus() and chrome_dialog.set_focus() working for you?

Comment: No, I have tried that also, it gives me an error saying that the program is unable to find Chrome

Comment: Maybe window title doesn't contain `"Google Chrome"`? Connect by title is right way. But correct title is also important.

Comment: The title is correct so that is not the problem, I will update in a few hours with a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer I was looking for here:
[Python win32gui set-as-foreground-window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200381/python-win32gui-setasforegroundwindow-function-not-working-properly)

You can get around the code and build your functionality