# I want to open an already opened app in Python

Tags: python, automation

I'm writing a simple program in Python and I need to change windows in which the application works multiple times. I could use pyautogui.click(x, y); to click on the taskbar but thats not efficent enough.

Is there anyway I can do it with a command like: open('appname') or: summon('appname')

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you can use [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and for more detail regarding your question you can visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222050/how-to-switch-between-two-application-using-pywinauto-0-5-4)

Answer (score 0):

you using GUI without Tkinter? very interesting. you need to open program with python script?
try:

`import os`

`# If program isnt in a folder with script`

`os.system("start LETTER:\Path\To\Program")`

`# If program in a folder with a script or program is a command in command line`

`os.system("start ProgramName")`

With it you can launch any program without limit (if you have a good CPU, GPU and RAM :D)

Comment: I don't need to open the program, I just need to bring up the window of the already opened program.

Example: I have a Excel spreadsheet opened but now i'm working in Chrome, i want now to bring up the window with Excel spreadsheet on it